# local file access on Google-Chrome-ARC?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Is there any way to implement local file access on ARC? As i understand Chrome is sandboxed, so access would be hard, but it seems that the defined android data directory could have a specific folder used for file access?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, application on ARC is sandboxed and unable to access to local file system.

However, you can access to the file on your local file system by starting Activity with specific Intent: ACTION_GET_CONTENT for reading file and ACTION_SEND for saving file.

e.g. If you would like to open image file from your local file system,

```
private static int REQUEST_CODE = 5;

private void requestImageFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        imgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        setContentView(imgView);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I want to use this method, but need to access the file and pull data from it. I can choose the file, but the file path is not like a normal file path. I am trying to grab a .csv and pull the data from it to display in the application. My quesiton is how do I got about saving the file so i can access it?

Answer (score 0):

> ARC app may have access to OS Filesystem (via browser file chooser), but will not be able to modify them, i.e. ARC will first copy these items to a different location and feed the app with the copy instead of the original file.

**Further read :**

https://sslab.gtisc.gatech.edu/2014/arc-security.html